# String parsing with regex

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string value that needs to be parsed with a regular expression. It may contain words, numbers and special chars in any order. What is the easiest expression for that?

Comment: Why parse it if you allow everything :D

Comment: And improve this question. What do you want as a result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.*
```

should work.